# MongoDB: A refers to B. Get A's whose B's satisfy some conditions

Tags: database, mongodb, query-optimization, query-performance

## Setup

We have two collections:

- **maps:** Each document has an _id and coordinates fields. The coordinates field is a GeoJSON LineString that represents a route.
  We have around 200K maps
- **segments:** Each document holds details about a route (elevation, athelete count etc) and has a map field which holds the _id of a certain map.
  We have around 230K segments (some of them are not ignored).
  The relationship between maps and segments is a one-to-one relationship.

## Use case

Our server receives query which specifies:

- The view/rectangular bound in GeoJSON format
- Other filters like range of athlete count etc

## Current solution

Right now our process looks like this:

1. Get all the maps whose any point lies inside the rectangular bounds
   The query looks something like this:

```
   {
          coordinates: {
              $geoIntersects: {
                  $geometry: {
                    type: "Polygon",
                    coordinates: [bounds],
                  }
              },
            }
   }
```

2. Get an array of the maps _id s  that satisfy this constraint
3. Get the segments that contain an id of those _ids :

```
    {
         map: { $in: mapIds }
    }
```

4. Populate their map field on the server directly

## Problem

The problem is that our query is too slow.
Our collections are properly indexed. We have a 2dsphere indexing on the coordinates field of the map
The bottleneck seems to be in step 3). The mapIds array may be too big and the database might be doing too many comparisons.

## Question

Is there a way, maybe another operator we can use, to make this query more efficient?

I am not even sure what type of query this would fall under, but it some kind of a reverse populate where the condition is not on the populated but on the populated by, if that makes sense.

I was thinking maybe I could use the aggregate operation with some $lookup but I am not sure how to use it.

Any help is welcome.